# Prove inequality $\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^{\lceil n\log n+ cn\rceil}\leq n e^{-(n\log(n)+cn)/n}$

Tags: inequality

Can anyone help me see why this inequality holds?
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^{\lceil n\log n+ cn\rceil}\leq n e^{-(n\log(n)+cn)/n}$$
Any help is appreciated

Comment: The term inside summation is independent of $i$. Is that a typo?

Comment: No, it is not but you are right, the question could have been simplified by removing the summation and dividing the other side by $n$.

Comment: Is $c$ positive? Are there any other information about $c$ ?

Comment: Yes $c\gt 0$ and $n$ is a positive integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $\; e^x\ge 1+x\ge 0 \;$ for $\; x\ge-1 \; \;$  $\textbf{(*)}$

$ e^{rx}\ge (1+x)^r \; $ for $\; r\ge 0  $ $\\$

Using the inequality gives us for $x=\frac{-1}{n} \;$ and $\; r=\lceil n\log n+ cn\rceil\ge 0 \; \;$  (I assumed $c\ge 0$ here)

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^{\lceil n\log n+ cn\rceil}=\sum_{i=1}^n\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\lceil n\log n+ cn\rceil}\leq\sum_{i=1}^ne^{-(\lceil n\log n+ cn\rceil)/n}\\$$

$$\le\sum_{i=1}^ne^{-( n\log n+ cn)/n}= ne^{-( n\log n+ cn)/n}$$

$\textbf{(*):}$ $\;$ For $\; x=0 \; \;$ and $\; x=-1 \; $ the inequality is true. $ \; \; \frac{\partial [e^x-(1+x)]}{\partial x}\ge 0 \;$ for  $\; x\ge 0 \; \;$ and $\; \; \frac{\partial [e^x-(1+x)]}{\partial x}\le 0 \; $ for  $\; x\le 0 \; \;$

Comment: Where did the inequality $(1+x)^r\leq e^{rx}$ come from?

Comment: I have edited the solution